# c# Encoding.UTF8.GetString unacceptable performance time

Tags: c#, .net

I have following code, which do it's job fine:

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = (XmlDocument)myReportOrginal.Clone();

        MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream();
        xmlDoc.Save(xmlStream);
        //heavy part
        string[] lines = Encoding.UTF8.
              GetString(xmlStream.ToArray()).
              Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Eventually after running it's able to achieve goal (in that particular case it's getting array of strings). However my problem here is fact that xmlDoc might be sometimes huge (100 000 or more xml lines). In such situation performance time is really bad (around 30 minutes).
How to fix that? Is there better/faster method ?

Result of string's array is for 2 purpose:

1. to do a little changes like

   ```
        for (int i = ((int)lines.Length - 1); i >= 0; i--)
        {
            lines = lines.Where(o => !o.Contains("rootTemp")).ToArray();
        }

        lines[0] = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
   ```
2. finally create a new xml document:

   ```
        TempXmlOutputResult = new XmlDocument();
        TempXmlOutputResult.LoadXml(String.Concat(lines));
   ```

Comment: Have you measured this properly? Right now you are retrieving the byte array, decoding it to a string and splitting it in the same line. Are you sure that it is `UTF8.GetString` that takes up all that time?

Comment: Yes, I measured it. And from debbuging perspective assigning  string[] lines = tooks around 30min for big xml string.

Comment: "assigning `string[] lines =`" as you say, do minimum 4 operations, have you checked them separately?

Comment: No. Only assigning. Sorry for bying not precise.

Comment: Use a `StreamReader` instead. In general, try rewriting everything being done here as stream-based operations, because copying around big chunks of memory is expensive, and it happens multiple times here. If you can express the operations you're doing in terms of XML instead of manipulating strings (for example, removing the `rootTemp` element instead of "a line that happens to contain `rootTemp`"), so much the better. Ideally you want to process the whole document only once, and then not by splitting it up into lines.

Comment: The fact with rootTemp is  that I don't want to delete it's content, but only open and close tags rootTemp.

Comment: If you want to optimize something then you first need to know what is taking up the time. For starters, split the `string[] lines = ...` into several statements, one that gets the array, one that converts the array to a string and one that splits the string. Then measure which of them takes the most time (and maybe check the memory usage of your app while doing this). It might as well be `Split` that is really slow when you throw an enormous string at it.

Comment: Another thing that could impact possible solutions here is what version of .NET you are running. If this is .NET Core or .Net > 5 a solution using Spans might also be worth checking out.

Comment: .Net Framework 4.7.2.  And you are right -faulty is Split.  If I set up   string lines = Encoding.UTF8. GetString(xmlStream.ToArray()).ToString(); It's fine. But in case when I still need to modify it  with : lines.Replace("<rootTemp xmlns=\"\">","");    lines.Replace("</rootTemp>", ""); Then program doesn't replace it. What is proper way of a such approach?

Comment: Ok. Topic can be closed while it related with Split instead of Encoding.UTF8.GetString. Thank you all for replays.